# Can't have 2 blob trigger functions in the same FA listening on the same container

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-trigger

I have single FA that contains 2 functions.
Both are triggered from the same container, but on different filters.

When I do that, I get following error:

[image]

**Function 1**

[image]

**Function 2**

[image]

I event tried creating a new container, and having 2 different containers in functions, but result is the same. Can't find anything on the official MSDN docs.

Comment: The recommended way to do different logics on same storage account related changes is to use `Event Grid` based triggers. see this [msdn answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f6bbcf1-c496-4ac3-8e19-09bd4f123451/multiple-functions-using-blob-trigger-with-same-path?forum=AzureFunctions)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran the thing is that I have 2 functions because one is for the old version of the software, and the new one is for the new. So it would be great if I could still keep FA with functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the length of the blob name. Emulator allows blob name with 256 chars, so after I changed *AzureWebJobsStorage* to use storage ACC (it allows 1000 chars), everything continued working as expected